# How to return SQL DataReader data

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to SQL Server so sorry if my question seems trivial but I have not been able to find a good answer to this or at least one that I can utilize.

My problem is that I need to use sql datareader to get table GUIDs which I will use later to insert entries into another database. Closing the datareader disposes of all information inside of it and I have not been able to find how to return the datareader values so that I can call them later in my code. How do you return or store datareader values to be called upon later?

Comment: You have to keep the reader open while using the data or else you will need to store it in a temp location (again before closing it). You could also just use a datatable.

Comment: create a List<Guid> and add the Guids to that and return it, it'll be easier to work with

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: read them and put in any suitable container, like `List<T>`(any other generic collection or just array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than returning the data reader add all of the values to a collection. Here you'll want a `List<T>` or `T[]` (array). This should contain objects that model the results of your query. If you're only returning the Guids then it would be `List<Guid>` or `Guid[]`.

In general, all of your db interactions should be in one layer of the application. It's at that point that you want to deserialize query results. Elsewhere in your code you should deal with native C# types rather than a query result that is still pending deserialization. Here you generally just want methods that take whatever data is necessary to form a query and return an object or a collection of objects which model the query results.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy help. I ended up using ebyrob's suggestion but your suggestion is more general and should help other readers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just store it to a DataTable:

```
SqlDataReader dr = null; // something you already have
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
```

Now all the rows and columns should be available in the DataTable until you're done using it.

Note: DataTable lives at: System.Data.DataTable.

Comment: Thanks this one worked out the best for me, it helped me bypass a lot of the work that the other options needed. Although I think using a more general List<> option would apply to more users.

Comment: @JuanPortela Interesting that you notice this is useful but think a "more general" POCO solution would work for others.  These 3 lines of code work for pretty much every SQL query with a result set.  Dissecting and storing the result into lists of (probably user objects) requires custom code for each query (not to mention creating the storage types)

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it (In the data-layer):

```
public List<Guid> GetAllIds()
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(yourConnectionString, "SELECT yourIDColumn from YourTable")

    var ids = new List<GUID>();
    Using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        ids.Add(reader.GetGuid(0))
      }
    }
  return ids;
}
```